# use WCF service from Android Application

Tags: android, wcf, httprequest, httpresponse

i have so far worked on visual c#. but now i m trying to develop android applications.

i need my android application to communicate with a WCF Service. and i m new to both android and the idea of WCF services, can anyone give me an example on how to write an WCF service that can communicate with an android application.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All services can be used by Android (REST).

[how to consume web service with android in general](http://romenlaw.blogspot.com/2008/08/consuming-web-services-from-android.html)